# How to read number to string till end of the line in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, input, eol

I have an input file like this

```
10 25 4 3 86 1 23 20 14 1 3 7 3 16 7
2
```

The 1st line: An array of number.

The 2nd line: An integer k.

I tried **fgets()** to read them but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    FILE *input = fopen("Input7.txt","r");
    int a[2000],k;
    fgets(a,2000,input);
    fscanf(input,"%d",&k);
    fclose(input);
    int i,n;
    n = 15; //My example array have 15 numbers
    for (i=1;i<=n;++i){
        printf("%d  ",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I printed out the array a after i read it but here is what i got
[Photo links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekUOI.jpg)

How can i fix this problem ? Btw, i want to count how much number i've read into the array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "it's not working" part?

Comment: Maybe go all the way to making a [mcve].

Comment: fgets() is to read a string and it takes a char*, not an int*. You need to read in the string, and then parse the string to fill up your int[].

Comment: Do you not get any errors or warnings compiling that code? your array `a` is not the correct type for using with `fgets`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i updated my post

Comment: @torstenvl can you show me how to do this. i'm really new at C and C++

Comment: @ChrisTurner i got an warning but i ignored it, it's still run but not correct :(

Comment: How do you print the array? As others have pointed out, we need a [mcve] to be able to reproduce the error and tell you what is wrong. Otherwise the question is off topic for SO.

Comment: Don't ignore warnings - they're a sign your code is wrong.

Comment: @muXXmit2X i updated my code, thanks <3

Comment: @ChrisTurner here is the warning: passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: If you look at the prototype of fgets, the first param is char*, but you are supplying int[].  Try to fix the warnings (without using a cast).  They are there for a reason.

Comment: @HoàngTùngLâm we already knew what the warning was cos it's obvious from your code

Comment: @ChrisTurner are there any easier way to read as i want ?

Comment: Post your output here as text is more useful.  Posting text as images or worse, links to images, attracts down-votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the type of your `a` array to `char`, because the [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) waits for `char*` as first parameter.

The next important thing is that `fgets` read the characters into the specified `char` array not the numbers directly, you have to tokenize the charater sequence you read and convert each token to integer. You can tokenize your `a` array with the [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) function.

```
#include <stdio.h> // for fgets, printf, etc.
#include <string.h> // for strtok

#define BUFFER_SIZE 200

int main() {
    FILE* input = fopen("Input7.txt", "r");
    char a[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char* a_ptr;

    int k, i = 0, j;
    int n[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };

    fgets(a, BUFFER_SIZE, input); // reading the first line from file
    fscanf(input, "%d", &k);

    a_ptr = strtok(a, " "); // tokenizing and reading the first token
    while(a_ptr != NULL) {
        n[i++] = atoi(a_ptr); // converting next token to 'int'
        a_ptr = strtok (NULL, " "); // reading next token
    }

    for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) // the 'i' can tell you how much numbers you have
        printf(j ? ", %d" : "%d", n[j]);
    printf("\n");

    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: `{}` is invalid C initializer (I believe it's valid C++); though gcc accepts it if invoked without `-pedantic`. The valid "*universal zero initializer*" is `{0}`.

Comment: @pmg, thanks for the clarification. Yes it's valid in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the line thing...

Just keep reading numbers until EOF

```
int array[1000];
int k = 0;
int prev, last;
if (scanf("%d", &prev) != 1) /* error */;
while (scanf("%d", &last) == 1) {
    array[k++] = prev;
    prev = last;
}
// array has the k numbers in the first line
// prev has the single number in the last line
```

If you want, make array dynamic with `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help